# Closedness of the subset [0,1] in $\Bbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through the definitions given in **2.18** in Baby Rudin, and I was wondering how to prove that $E = [0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}$ is closed in $\Bbb{Q}$.

Clearly, the set $[0,1] \cap \Bbb{R}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$, since for all neighborhoods of a point $p \in [0,1]$, we can always find a $q \neq p$ such that $q \in [0,1]$. Intuitively, this is because for all $p \in [0,1] \cap \Bbb{R}$, we can always find a $q \in [0,1] \cap \Bbb{R}$ such that $p - \epsilon < q < p$ or $p < q < p+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

However, that the set $E = [0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}$ is closed in $\Bbb{Q}$ is sort of clear, but not intuitive to me, since $\Bbb{Q}$ is not uncountably infinite as $\Bbb{R}$ is. Does one have to use that fact that it is closed in $\Bbb{R}$ and that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$? How would one solve it from first principles? i.e. Something along the lines of: Consider an arbitrary $p \in [0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}$, we show that it is a limit point by...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since $[0,1]\not\subset\mathbb Q$, your question makes no sense. Did you mean that $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb Q$? And you do you mean when you say that $\mathbb Q$ is not continuous?

Comment: "$\Bbb Q$ is not continuous"? It is functions that may or may not be continuous, not sets. Just show the complement of $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ is open in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Interval notation works in any total order. It's _most commonly_ used in $\Bbb R$, but I've seen it used generally as well.

Comment: @Arthur I am not sure that that's clear in the OP's mind.

Comment: What I meant by $[0,1] \subset \Bbb{Q}$ was the subset [0,1] of $\Bbb{Q}$. i.e. the rational numbers between 0 and 1 inclusive. @JoséCarlosSantos that was perfectly clear in my mind. In any case, I have edited the post so it is more understandable

Comment: Then you should type $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It is pretty easy to show that the complement of the set [0,1] $\cap \Bbb{Q}$ is open. $$\mathbb{Q} \setminus \left (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \right ) = \mathbb{Q} \cap \left ( (-\infty , 0) \cup (1,\infty) \right ) $$
All of these are open in $\mathbb{Q}$ so the result is open too, making the original set closed. In particular, I want some help in showing that its closed without using the complement.

Comment: One thing that helped me was to realize that a *sub*space is really just the whole space but with seen through filters of parts blocked off.  What ever is open (fuzzy) in the whole will be open (fuzzy) in the part and what ever is closed (sharp) in the whole will be closed (sharp) in the part because there is no "outside" of the part from which to look.  Everything we see *inside* the part will have the same characteristics that it did in the whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say I couldn't follow your argument that it is intuitive $[0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ at all.

$[0,1]$ is closed (in $\mathbb R$) because all its limit points are in in $[0,1]$.  That is; If $p \in \mathbb R$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ it will always be that the interval $(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$ will contain a point $q \in [0,1]$, then we can conclude that $p$, itself, is in $[0,1]$.

Pf:  If $p < 0$ and $\epsilon = 0 - p= |p|$ then $(p-\epsilon, p + \epsilon) = (2p, 0)$ is disjoint from $[0,1]$ and there is no point, $q$, in common with $[0,1]$.  And if $p > 0$ and $\epsilon = p - 1$ then $(p-\epsilon, p+ \epsilon) = (1, 2p - 1)$ and there is no point, $q$, in common with $[0,1]$.

So if $p$ is a limit point (if there *are* any limit points, there might not be) then it would have to be that $0 \le p \le 1$ so $p \in [0,1]$.

Thus by definition $[0,1]$ is closed.

.....

But notice there is *nothing* in that proof that pertains to any property of $\mathbb R$ and it would have held true for any subspace of $\mathbb R$ at all.  Everything we said would be true for $\mathbb Q$ or any $B \subset \mathbb R$.

Also, although the proof to show $[0,1]$ was closed was particular to $[0,1]$, there is no proof of any other set being closed that would rely upon  the space.

**Claim**: If $A$ is closed in space $X$ then $A\cap Y$ is closed in $Y \subset X$.

Pf:  Let $p \in Y$ be a limit point of $A\cap Y$ then every neighborhood, $N$ of $p$ contains a point $q; q \ne p; q \in A\cap Y\subset A$.  But then $N$ is a subset of a neighborhood $N'\subset X$.  $q \in A$ and $q \in N'$.  So $p$ is a limit point of $A$.   And as $A$ is closed in $X$ that means $p \in A$. And as $p \in Y$.  So $p \in A\cup Y$.  So $A\cup Y$ is closed in $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

The density of $\mathbb Q$ plays no role here. If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$ and $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, then $A\cap B$ is a closed subset of $B$. That's so because the complement of $A\cap B$ in $B$ is equal to $A^\complement\cap B$. Now, since $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, $A^\complement$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and therefore $A^\complement\cap B$ is an open subset of $B$.

Comment: This was helpful, and I now see why it doesn't matter that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in the reals. But in particular what I wanted was a way to show that an arbitrary $p \in [0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}$ is a limit point in $[0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}$

Comment: @PhysMath Why? The set $(0,1)$ is **not** closed in $\mathbb R$. Nevertheless, each of its points **is** a limit point of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @PhysMath You got the definition wrong. The direction was reversed. Your goal should be that every limit point of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ lies in $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$, not the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

A bit formal :

Baby Rudin: Theorem 2.30.

Suppose $Y \subset X$. $A$ subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$

$\iff$

$E=Y \cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.

$B= [0,1]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

$B^c:= \mathbb{R}$\ $[0,1]$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Hence

$(B^c \cap \mathbb{Q})$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

The complement of $(B^c \cap \mathbb{Q})$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ :

$\mathbb{Q} - (B^c \cap \mathbb{Q})=$

$\mathbb{Q} \cap (B^c \cap \mathbb{Q})^c =$

$\mathbb{Q} \cap (B \cup \mathbb{Q}^c)=$

$(\mathbb{Q} \cap B)\cup (\mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{Q}^c)=$

$\mathbb{Q} \cap B$.

Comment: Absolutely true.  Theorem 2.30 basically says this must be true.  The question is intuitively why is 2.30 true... and I guess.... well, whatever we say about points being in or not in neighborhoods or a set E will be true of points being in or not in intersections of neighborhoods or a set E with a subspace of X.  Once we intuitively "grok" the definitions the result is obvious. (The only issue of doubt a student could have, I think, is there must be some intuitive *real* space "out there" that border of the subspace "cuts off".  In which case we need to understand what a *sub*space means.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Your answer and comment show that you are well at ease, while I am at times happy to get from A to B (prove something for a closed set B, starting with 2.30 for an open set A :))Greetings.